# Change how facet filters are applied to the URL in Big Commerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I need to make some changes to how the url is constructed when a user uses a faceted search filed on the Big Commerce category pages.

By default the url has the following params added `?color[]=red&color[]=blue`, but I need to update too `color=red|blue` for example.

If anyone could provide some insight on how to achieve this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Moody1208! 
Although there could be a workaround to change the url structure to being closer to what you're looking for, I wouldn't recommend doing so as the url will not work at all if changed. Therefore, I'd say this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need this functionality, I would recommend using a third party app. The functionality you are looking for simply is not possible with BigCommerce's native faceted search.

You can try [SearchSpring](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/searchspring/), [Instant Search +](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/instantsearch/) , [Searchanise](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/searchanise/), or [SOBooster](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/ultimate-search-product-filter-by-sobooster/).